# How to get current Time with Milli second precision ( C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, time

I use `System.DateTime.Now` , but it return like `5/28/2011 1:45:58 AM` .(no Milli second precision)

I would like to save current time (or Date time )   with Milli second precision in database .

Update : Sorry , I meant **Milli** Second

Comment: The 58 in 1:45:58 represents the seconds ... Perhaps I am misunderstanding your question?

Comment: You are right , I'm so sorry , I edit the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`System.DateTime` manages precision to the millisecond, `5/28/2011 1:45:58 AM` is just how it was formatted to a String.

To format with millisecond included use format string: `"d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt"`

Comment: The clock (.Now) is 'precise' up to about 20 ms.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store it in a SQL Server database, ADO.Net automatically converts the CLR `System.DateTime` datatype to a SQL Server `datetime` datatype (and vice-versa).

The CLR `System.DateTime` has 100-nanosecond precision (e.g., each tick is 100 nanoseconds; 10,000 ticks per millisecond, 10 million ticks per second.

The SQL Server datetime datatype is precise to (approximately) 3ms.

You shouldn't need to worry about it: ADO.Net will take care of it for you.

OTOH, if you really want to throw away extra nanoseconds, something like this ought to do the trick:

```
public static DateTime ToExactMillisecondPrecision( DateTime dt )
{
  const long TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND = 10000 ;
  long       totalMilliseconds     = dt.Ticks / TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND ;

  return new DateTime( totalMilliseconds * TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND ) ;
}
```

Can't really see the need myself.

Comment: Just to add that if on SQL Server 2008 `datetime2` allows for millisecond precision.

Answer (score 1):

Look under the properties list in this link.  All the different options are there.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Including [seconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.second.aspx), [milliseconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.millisecond.aspx), and [ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The string you posted contains seconds, so I suppose you're not asking for second precision, but for more precise timing.

The value of `DateTime.Now` is returned with more than millisecond precision. it's just that with default formatting, the milliseconds aren't displayed. To display the value with milliseconds, you can either use [the `o` standard format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip), or write your own [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), that includes the millisecond format specifier `fff`.

Note that just because the returned value is *precise*, it doesn't mean it's as much *accurate*. The actual accuracy is not defined exactly, but tends to be in tens of milliseconds.

Comment: Which format should I use in order to have millisecond either ?

Answer (score 0):

It should not be necessary to convert the date to string. Perhaps the real problem is that you using dynamic SQL.